# Why div align to left when change display property as table-cell?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, tablecell

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="article">
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.table {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#ccc;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.content {    
    background-color:#f00;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I want to align .content div as horizontally and vertically center in page. Also I want to align .article div as vertically center in .content div. But when I use table-cell property for .content div, it align to left. I want it as;

[image]

But it look like this;

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/snu306fh/2/

Why and how can I fix?

Comment: is it browser-specific problem

Comment: I don't think, I've tried two different browsers (chrom,firefox)

Comment: see an update to my second answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be making .content a display: table and use .article as wrapper ( and  adding display: table-cell to it )

http://jsfiddle.net/snu306fh/6/

```
.content {    
   background-color:#f00;
   width: 500px;
   height: 300px;
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align: left;
   color: #fff;
   display:table;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.article {
   padding: 20px;
   display: table-cell;
}
```

Now I hope everyone happy?

**UPD: Mb this is what u actually looking for**

http://jsfiddle.net/snu306fh/11/

If you add to .article vertical-align - you will get content of centered div - also to be centered

```
.content {    
    background-color:#f00;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    display:table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.article {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You should edit your other question with this answer

Comment: @Dejan.S I don't think so. The other answer is also valid one ( from my point of view )

Comment: You should update your question with this as compliment to the other. It will be removed eventually. btw that other is not what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @Dejan.S Just removed other answer that had "dark side in it", hope that "the force" is in balance again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .content
        {
            background-color: #f00;
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: left;
            color: #fff;
            display: table; 
            vertical-align:middle;

        }
```

using table in display property

http://jsfiddle.net/snu306fh/7/

Answer (score 0):

If you need centered block on a page, you can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qqrh68ya/

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
.inner {
  background-color:#f00;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
}
```

If my answer is incorrect and you need tables, explain please why :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.div-father
{
background-color: black;
width: 400px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: -webkit-center;
height: 400px;
}
.div-chield
{
background-color:red;
width:200px;
height:200px;
text-align: justify;
}
```